# Images in Heroku PostgreSQL does not accept image binay data and uses \ character

Tags: postgresql, heroku, heroku-postgres

I do not understand why I can not see the image that I have inserted in my heroku postgresql and why the images are full of \ characters when I load them from the website itself.

This is the update statement that works fine in the localhost and shows the images correctly:

```
UPDATE blog SET IMAGE= '89504e40_I_DELETED_THE PART_IN_BETWEEN_TO MAKE_IT _SHORTER_90b21a0508bee0e2cde637fd31c249274ecce90000000049454e44ae426082', IMAGE_CONTENT_TYPE='image/png' where id>0;
```

When I get in the heroku database with PGAdmin4 I see it like [binary data] and it is not shown in the web, BUT when I download a CSV from the database the images are there.

AND when I enter in the website and change an image, it goes into the database without problem as [binary data], downloads on the CSV BUT with a difference: it is full of \ and the characters

```
8,"2018-06-08 08:08:00","Blog Title 8 COMMUNITY_ID 5","\377\330\377\340\000\020JFIF\000\001\001\000\000\001\000\001\000\000\377\333\000\204\000\011\006\007\010\007\006\011\010\007\010\012\012\011\013\015\026\017\015\014\014\015\033\024\025\020\026 \035"""" \035\037\_DELETE_THE_MIDDLE_40?\377\331","image/jpeg","5"
```

This is regular image that shows no \ in the data:

```
8,"2018-06-08 08:08:00","Blog Title 8 COMMUNITY_ID 5","89504e470d0a1a0a0000000d4948c249274ecce90000000049454e44ae426082","image/png","5"
```

What is heroku postgresql changing here? Are they using a different format? What can I change in my update statement to make it work directly?

Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should DECODE it like this:

UPDATE blog SET IMAGE= decode('89504e470d0a1a0a0000000d4948445200000103000000c208030000007acc575c00000003504c5445000000a77a3dda0000004849444154789cedc13101000000c2a0f54f6d0c1fa000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000080b701c508000164aa1fd00000000049454e44ae426082', 'hex'), IMAGE_CONTENT_TYPE='image/png' where id>0;

See this answer [Transition H2 data to PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15873848/transition-h2-data-to-postgresql)