# H2 vs Postgres in handling of BYTEA

Tags: java, postgresql, h2, liquibase

I have a project with Java 11 + Spring Boot 2 + Liquibase + Postgres 11.
There is a task to make SQL dump of table from a legacy Oracle DB and craft a migration from it. Table has a BYTEA columnt with small GIF images (~400 bytes, tiny icons). Migration should be applied successfuly not only to Postgres, but to H2 in test as well.
But there is an issue, that H2 and Postgress, seemingly, have a different syntax for HEX literals, when inserting into a BYTEA column.
As far as I googled, H2 requires X'0123456789ABCDEF' and Postgres requires '\x0123456789ABCDEF'.
When I try to apply the migration to H2 with Postgres HEX syntax, an exception "Hexadecimal string contains non-hexadecimal characters" is thrown.
Are there any workarounds or proper way to do such a thing?

Comment: Does [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15873848/transition-h2-data-to-postgresql) helps you? It suggests to use PostgreSQL `decode(filedata-in-hex, 'hex')` function.

Comment: @RakhiAgrawal hey, thanks a lot, it works, but I have chosen to use Liquibase feature to bypass the issue of the question. Liquibase allows to have 2 separate changesets in 1 SQL formatted file, demarcated by ```--changeset author:id dbms:h2``` and ```--changeset author:id dbms:postgresql```. Very convinient attribute.

Comment: great! Thanks for the another approach. Will prove helpful to others in future.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Transition H2 data to PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15873848/transition-h2-data-to-postgresql)

Comment: @AbdelrhmanArnos it has already been suggested in the first comment. It works, thx.